# PowerShell Out-GridView handle Click/DoubleClik event

Tags: powershell, gridview, event-handling

After sent data to a GridView (Out-GridView)

How can I create a event that handle row-click (row-select)

Or a event that handles double-click and closes the GridView
providing the selected rows in a variable

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a 'row select event' for `Out-GridView`, or a way to double-click an item in the list.

However, this example shows how to select items from an array using an `Out-GridView`. Pipe your data through the `Out-GridView` CmdLet and use the `-PassThru` switch to allow the user to select items. `PassThru` implies `-Wait` which suspends the script and waits for the user to select items, or close the window:

```
$viewme = @('pick','one','of','these')

$selection = $viewme | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Pick item(s)'
```

If I click `Cancel` or close the window, the `$selection` variable is null:

```
$selection -eq $null
True
```

Otherwise if I *do* select items, they are returned in an object of type `System.Array`:

```
$selection
one
these
```

Comment: excelent mjsqu... and permits also multiple selection that will be available in the output variable... Thanks...